# Is it possible to change the projection used in OSM2PO?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2po

Is it possible to change the projection used in OSM2PO? I used the following command to generate a `SQL` file which I loaded into my database:

```
java -jar osm2po-core-4.2.30-signed.jar prefix=at "filename.osm.pbf.pbf"
```

This produce the file `at_2po_4pgr.sql`. I then loaded this file into my postgres database:

```
psql -U postgres  -d routing -a -f at_2po_4pgr.sql
```

As this table is based on SRID:4326, I wondered if there was any way of changing it so that I can use a different projection system. The columns in the table are as follows:

```
  id integer NOT NULL,
  osm_id bigint,
  osm_name character varying,
  osm_source_id bigint,
  osm_target_id bigint,
  clazz integer,
  flags integer,
  source integer,
  target integer,
  km double precision,
  kmh integer,
  cost double precision,
  reverse_cost double precision,
  x1 double precision,
  y1 double precision,
  x2 double precision,
  y2 double precision,
  geom_way geometry(LineString,4326),
  CONSTRAINT pkey_at_2po_4pgr PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

I know that I can use `ST_Transform to convert`geom_way` into a different projection but I was unsure how to update any of the other values as I presumed some were based on the initial projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 ST_Transform(geom_way,<new crs>)
```

Then update x1,y1,x2,y2

```
 UPDATE table_name SET x1 = X(ST_StartPoint(geom_way))
```

etc.

Same for updating km and the related cost

```
 UPDATE table_name SET km = ST_Length(geom_way)
```

Comment: I'll try it out. I was a bit nervous changing it in case I misunderstood how these values were being calculated but this seems like a good approach.

Comment: Hmmm. The major question is, if pgRouting looks up the srs in the spatialRefSys- and geometry-colums-Table or not. If it depends on WGS84, there is nothing to change here because these values are only used for calculating heuristics.

Comment: While I cannot be absolutely certain without looking into the sources, I certainly wouldn't expect pgRouting to be CRS dependent.

Answer (score 2):

osm2po does export EPSG 4326 only.

As geom_way is a pure PosgGIS data type, you can indeed change it using ST_Transform.
x1, y1, x2, y2 are hard coded values for pgRouting's aStar.
I do not know what will happen if you transform them also.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to transform `x1, y1, x2, y2` as they are not geometric or geographic objects. However, if they are only used for `aStar` maybe it it does not matter too much.

Comment: Yes, they are only used for aStar. Maybe Daniel is following this thread and can give you some more infos.

Answer (score 0):

I've included how I did this using @underdark's suggestion. Perhaps of use to someone else:

```
CREATE TABLE osm2po_routing_prj AS
SELECT
  id,
  osm_id,
  osm_name,
  osm_source_id,
  osm_target_id,
  clazz,
  flags,
  source,
  target,
  ST_Length(ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913)) as km,
  kmh,
  cost,
  reverse_cost,
  ST_X(ST_StartPoint(ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913))) as x1,
  ST_Y(ST_StartPoint(ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913))) as y1,
  ST_X(ST_EndPoint(ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913))) as x2,
  ST_Y(ST_EndPoint(ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913))) as y2,
  ST_Transform(geom_way, 900913) as geom_way
FROM osm2po_routing;
```

Comment: Just be aware that length measurements in 900913 can be quite wrong.

Comment: True, good point.

Comment: Anyway, I think it is not necessary to reproject a length.